# Make Total in PHP with SubTotal from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem about make total in PHP.

I'd like to make total in my Web App (PHP based) but I get subtotal from database MySQL. And I will print it into table.

Here it is my code :

```
<table class="ui single selectable table">
  <tbody>
    <?php
    $idTrx = $_POST['idTrx'];
    $idUser = substr($idTrx, 3);
    $total;

    $query = "select trx.id_trx, tempTrx.id_user,  tempTrx.nameProduct as nameProduct, tempTrx.price as price, tempTrx.qty as qty, tempTrx.subtotal as subtotal from trx,tempTrx where (trx.id_trx='" . $idTrx . "' and trx.status='1') and tempTrx.id_user='" . $idUser . "';";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);


    while ( $data = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
      echo "<tr><td>x</td><td>".$data['nameProduct']."</td><td>".$data['price']."</td><td>"
        .$data['qty']."</td><td>".$data['subtotal']."</td></tr>";

      for ($i=0; $i < count($data) ; $i++) { 
        $total += $data['subtotal'];
      }
    }

    ?>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Total
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th><?php echo $total ?></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I don't know how to make total from `$data['subtotal']` with specific amount of `$data`.

After I added `$total += $data['subtotal'];`, I still don't get correct `$total` from it.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem with your code is? It appears to be adding all `$data['subtotal']` to `$total`. Is `$total` not correct? Why are you performing the `for` loop inside the `while` loop?

Comment: @neuromatter - Yes, I've been added all `$data['subtotal']` to `$total`. But the `$total` is still not correct yet. I make `for` loop inside the `while` loop cause I think with that way I can get all of `$data['subtotal']` and I can get total from it.

Comment: Try removing the `for` loop but leaving `$total += $data['subtotal'];`. Can you provide an example of subtotal values and what they add up to (the incorrect total amount)?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Are the tables related to each other in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct value for $total, just add the value from $data['subtotal'] to $total, for each value returned from query. The for loop is not needed because you are going through each result from the query in the while loop. The way you have it now, it is adding the current value for $data['subtotal'] to $total multiple times (one for every count($data). So if count($data) is 10, it is adding the value for $data['subtotal'] 10 times per each row.  Simply add the current value for $data['subtotal'] to $total.

change

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data) ; $i++) { 
    $total += $data['subtotal'];
}
```

To

```
$total += $data['subtotal'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepting the valid points others have made in respect of parametrised queries, I find this easier to read:

```
SELECT a.id_trx
     , b.id_user
     , b.nameProduct 
     , b.price
     , b.qty 
     , b.subtotal 
  FROM trx a
 CROSS 
  JOIN tempTrx b
 WHERE a.id_trx = ?
   AND a.status = 1
   AND b.id_user= ?
```